# goroutines deadlock when using channels

Tags: go, parallel-processing, goroutine

Im new to go lang and I am trying to write a simple recursive algorithm which will use  goroutines. I am using channels to receive output from goroutine, but when I try to do so I receive "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!" error. If I comment out channels code everything runs fine.
This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    numbers := []int{2, -1, 10, 4, 3, 6, 22}

    ch := make(chan []int)

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go testFunc(numbers, ch, wg)
    wg.Wait()

    result := <-ch

    fmt.Println("Result: ", result)
}

func testFunc(numbers []int, ch chan []int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    ch <- numbers
}
```

What I am doing wrong  ? I am assigning value to channel in goroutine and reading it in main. Isn't that enough to communicate?

Comment: You're waiting for the goroutine before receiving from the channel. You have an unbuffered channel here, so you don't need the wait group, nor do you need the goroutine at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Communication on the unbuffered channel `ch` succeeds only when both a sender and receiver are ready.

The main function waits on the wait group before receiving the value.  The goroutine attempts to send on the channel before call wg.Done. It's a deadlock.

One fix is to use a buffered channel:

```
     ch := make(chan []int, 1)
```

Another fix is to receive on the channel before calling wg.Wait().

```
result := <-ch
wg.Wait()
```

Yet another fix is to delete all lines using the wait group. It's not needed in this specific example.

Comment: Buffering channel solved my problem. How I should change my current code and not use buffered channels?

Comment: Another fix is to receive on the channel before calling wg.Wait().

Comment: In which case (at least in this example) you don't need the wait group - you can't receive on the (unbuffered) channel until the function sends, which is the last thing it does before it returns.

Comment: Won't I need waitGroup if I will call two TestFunc go routines in main?

Comment: The comment applies to this specific example.  If you receive values from the two goroutines, then there's probably not a reason to use a goroutine.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, Whati want I want to do is to create a recursive sorting algorithm. It would use go routines to sort two array slices and then merge them. Is this a good approach? I need to do that in parallel.